# Facebook Marketing API Sometimes not Returning the Data

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I've been looking for hours and don't see any answers for my problem so here goes.

I am working with the Facebook Marketing API and while it's working fine for most metrics/breakdowns, some of them don't return anything but dates in the response.  Impressions, clicks, spend, etc. work just fine.  However, when I query the estimated_ad_recallers field I get only dates back.  The documentation says this:

> This metric is only available for assets in the Brand Awareness Objective

Does that mean if the campaign I'm querying has no ads for that asset then it just returns nothing?

Also, no matter what metric I query, if I use any of the asset breakdowns (e.g., ad_format_asset, call_to_action_asset, image_asset), the response just returns the metrics and pretends like I didn't ask for those breakdowns.

What am I missing?